# Applications of Neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am currently learning about Nueral Networks in Machine Learning and think it very interesting but I don't really know any other Applications NN have other than in Machine Learning and AI. I have tried researching these things but have come up short.

Could anyone tell me if you could use it in "Inventory management" or "Finance"? If you can would you have any examples?

Comment: Be honest; you didn't really [_try researching these things_](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Neural+Network+applications)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, is applied in most of the fields:

1. A simple search in google scholar will provide a list what include: fraud detection, stock market trading decision, inventory classification and many more, including the link below

[neural network inventory management](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,11&q=neural%20network%20inventory%20management)

1. As for Finance we can look at: credit scoring, bankruptcy forecast, financial forecasting and many more. Link from google scholar included below:

[neural network finance](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C11&q=neural%20network%20finance&btnG=)

Including also working example for simple credit scoring with NN:

[Using neural networks for credit scoring: a simple example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-neural-networks-for-credit-scoring-a-simple-example/)

Answer (score 0):

The question "how NN can be applied if not in machine learining" is incorrect. It's like "how cats can be applied if not in animals"?

Cats are animals. And **neural networks *are* a kind of machine learning**.

So a meaningful question is "where machine learning can be applied?", or "where statistics can be applied?", or "where math can be applied?". And the answer is: everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll rephrase. How can machine learning be applied in inventory management or finance.